# How to expand ComponentOne web report in C#

Tags: web, report, componentone

I am using componentOne web report in my system. Currently,we need to increase the width of the report to fit the entire screen. I have written java script to increase div width size, but data inside the report is not expanding based on the width. Please suggest a better approach.

```
  <cc1:C1WebReport ID="C1WebReport1"  runat="server" ExportFolder="/report/" Scrollable="False"                  
                    Visible="False" CallbackWaitImageUrl="~/Images/load.gif" class="control_label" Width="100%">                                  
                        <NavigationBar HasExportButton="True" Align="Center" HasGotoPageButton="True">
                            <Images ExportImageUrl="~/Images/ExportDetailsv2.png" GotoPageImageUrl="~/Images/gov6.png" />
                                <DisabledImages ExportImageUrl="~/Images/ExportDetailsv2.png"
                            GotoPageImageUrl="~/Images/gov6.png" />
                                <MouseOverImages ExportImageUrl="~/Images/ExportDetailsv2.png" GotoPageImageUrl="~/Images/gov6.png" />
                        </NavigationBar>
                    </cc1:C1WebReport>
```

Comment: Have you tried modifying Layout.Width property?

Comment: @Nilay : I have given width to 1100px in javascript document ready as follows:   ("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder3_C1WebReport1").width(1100);   But data inside the report is not expanding based on width.

Comment: Which of these can you say for sure: The width of C1WebReport element is not increasing or width of the report displayed in C1WebReport is not increasing?

Comment: @Nilay: when I reduced the width to 100px. The background-color became 100px but the data/report remained the same.

Comment: Report size is different from the element size. When you set the width to 100 px the viewer's size change, bu the width of the report is set in report's layout. See if you can modify the value of Layout.Width in report definition.

Comment: @Nilay: Thanks for the reply. But I am very new to this control. Don't know how increase width in report definition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133996/discussion-between-nilay-vishwakarma-and-psobhan).